# why eclipse cant find g++?

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, g++, eclipse-juno

Im running ubuntu and eclipse juno.
I have installed ctd, and g++ and gcc.

everything is working, but:

I have a simple hello world programm that comiles and runs and prints, 
but when i see the project in eclipse i see errors on std, namespace, cout .

in the error I get: g++ was not found in path

but g++ is installed.

this is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
return 0;
}
```

thank you.

Comment: What is the name of the file?

Comment: the file name is : HelloWorld.cpp

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse Configuration Environment add the path to g++ in the $PATH variable